# MySql Error 1093 (HY000) Insertion

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data into reservation table created using data query with no subqueries. But it shows up ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'reservation' for update in FROM clause

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    reservationID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    roomID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    customerName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    startDate DATE NOT NULL,
    endDate DATE NOT NULL,
    totalNumOfDays INT(10),
    totalCost DOUBLE(10,2),
    cancelled BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    updateOn TIMESTAMP  not null ON UPDATE current_timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY(reservationID),
    FOREIGN KEY(roomID) references room(roomID),
    FOREIGN KEY(customerName) references user(username));
ALTER table reservation auto_increment = 1000;

INSERT INTO reservation(roomID,
                        customerName, 
                        startDate,
                        endDate,
                        totalNumOfDays,
                        totalCost,
                        cancelled )
values ( 37, 'customer1',( SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,12,2017','%d,%m,%Y')),
( SELECT STR_TO_DATE('02,12,2017','%d,%m,%Y')),1,200,FALSE);
```

The value of roomID = 37, customerName ='customer1' are already in the table

Comment: Any triggers defined for this table ?

Comment: no I already dropped all the triggers

Comment: This is strange it works [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f526) there is something wrong on your DB, because on insert there is some event which tries to perform an update operation